# Javascript textbox keydown event

Tags: javascript, textbox, keydown

I have two textboxes, and when I write something, I want to change the color of p which is in another div if two textboxes have the same value.

So far I have written this, but it's not working:

```
<input id="sifre_text" type="text" />
<input id="sifre_tekrar_text" type="text" 
onkeydown="if(document.getElementById('sifre_tekrar_text').value
== if(document.getElementById('sifre_text').value')){
var c=document.getElementById('sifre_check').childNodes;    
c[1].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';}"/> 
<div id="sifre_check">
<p style="width:450px,height:350px"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use jQuery for your solution. If you are interested on it then please 
Try this:
HTML:

```
<input class="input-value" id="sifre_text" type="text" />
<input class="input-value" id="sifre_tekrar_text" type="text"/> 

<div id="sifre_check">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".input-value").on("change", function(){
        var a = $("#sifre_text").val();
        var b = $("#sifre_tekrar_text").val();
        if(a == b)
            $("#sifre_check").css("background-color", "yellow");     
    });
})
```

CSS:

```
#sifre_check {
    background-color: red; 
    width:450px; 
    height:350px
}
```